# Writing a test for a function that has been called on click

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have been trying to write some tests for a react component that I have built.  The component essentially passes values to its container on click of a certain button (which is another component)

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Button from '../../common/components/Button';
import Input from '../../common/components/Input';
import classNames from 'classnames';

class AddNewCellInputs extends React.Component {

  state = { value: '', shortName: '' }

  onChange = (e) => {
    let value = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ value: value })
  }

  onShortNameChange = (e) => {
    let shortName = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ shortName: shortName })
  }

  onAddCellSubmit = () => {
    const { value, shortName } = this.state
    this.props.onAddCellSubmit(shortName, value)
    this.setState({ value: '', shortName: '' })

  }


  render() {
    const { active, onNewCellClick } = this.props;
    const { value, shortName } = this.state
    return (
      <form className={classNames('csm__add-cell-form ', { 'active': active })}>
        <h3>Enter Cell Name</h3>
        <Input type="text" className="csm-modal-form__text-input" value={value} onChange={(e) => this.onChange(e)} />
        <Input type="text" className="csm-modal-form__text-input" value={shortName} onChange={(e) => this.onShortNameChange(e)} />

        <div className="csm__add-cell-form--button-container">
          <Button buttonClass="button-primary csm__button-add-cell" handleClick={() => this.onAddCellSubmit(shortName, value)} text="Add Cell" />
          <Button buttonClass="button-primary cancel" handleClick={onNewCellClick} text="Cancel" />
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }

}

export default AddNewCellInputs;

};
```

Here is the test

```
it('renders Call the addCellubmitMethod on lick of hte add-cell button', () => {
  const props = {
    active: true,
    onAddCellSubmit
  };
  let wrapper = mount(<AddNewCellInputs {...props} />);
  const onAddCellSubmit = jest.fn();
  wrapper.find('button').first().simulate('click');
  expect(onAddCellSubmit).toHaveBeenCalled();

});
```

This is the error i get

Uncaught [TypeError: _this.props.onAddCellSubmit is not a function].

I am new to testing so forgive me if i am doing something completely wrong

Comment: You are defining `onAddCellSubmit` after it has been used. This should not even work at all due to temporary dead zone.

Comment: You seem to be creating the `jest.fn()` **after** mounting the component, what is `onAddCellSubmit` before that?

Comment: Doublecheck that you're pass `onAddCellSubmit` function in props in test. If yes, please provide us with whole test file

Comment: This is my only test so far... aoart from rendering the component without it crashing

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this....

```
it('renders Call the addCellubmitMethod on lick of hte add-cell button', () => {
  const props = {
    active: true,
    onAddCellSubmit
  };
  let wrapper = mount(<AddNewCellInputs {...props} />);
  const onAddCellSubmitSpy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance(),'onAddCellSubmit');
  wrapper.find('button').first().prop('handleClick')();
  expect(onAddCellSubmitSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```